# How to update the icon of Action in NotificationCompat in Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-notifications

I am working with MediaPlayer and I am using **NotificationCompat.Builder** and **NotificationManagerCompat** for notification but when I play or pause the music the icon in notification bar doesn't change. I am using NotificationCompat MediaStyle.

Please suggest **how to change the icon of Action in notification**.

**Update:**

```
   private void setUpAsForground()
        {Log.e(TAG,"setUpAsForground");
             notificationbuilder
                .setContentIntent(pi);
               notificationbuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.sample_song_icon).setColor(ContextCo     mpat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));

        notificationbuilder.addAction(new     NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.ic_skip_previous_24dp, "prve",
                MediaStyleHelper.getActionIntent(this,    KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS)));

        notificationbuilder.addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_24dp, "playpause",
                MediaStyleHelper.getActionIntent(this, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE)));
        notificationbuilder.setOngoing(true);



    notificationbuilder.addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.ic_skip_next_24dp, "next",
            MediaStyleHelper.getActionIntent(this, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT)));

    notificationbuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.MediaStyle().setShowActionsInCompactView(1).setShowCancelButton(true).
            setCancelButtonIntent(MediaStyleHelper.getActionIntent(this, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_STOP)).setMediaSession(mediaSessionCompat.getSessionToken()));


  startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationbuilder.build());

}
    public void updateNotification(String type)
    {

        Log.e(TAG, "updateNotification");
        notificationbuilder.setContentTitle(currentSong.getTitle())
                .setColor(MyApplication.colorAccentLight)
               .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                 .setContentText(currentSong.getArtist());

              if  (mediaSessionCompat.getController().getPlaybackState().getState()==PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING )
             {
                 Log.e("mvcdg","play");
               NotificationCompat.getAction(notificationbuilder.build(),1).icon=R.drawable.ic_p    ause_24dp;
        notificationbuilder.setOngoing(true);

             }
        else
             {

                  Log.e("mvcdg", "pause");
                 NotificationCompat.getAction(notificationbuilder.build(),1).icon=R.drawable.ic_p    lay_arrow_24dp;
                notificationbuilder.setOngoing(false);

             }


        try {
          notificationbuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver()     .openInputStream(currentSong.getAlbumUriByAlbumId())));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        }

    notificationManagerCompat.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,     notificationbuilder.build());

}
```

Comment: can you paste the code which you are using to update the notification icon on play/pause state changes??

Comment: i pasted code for update the icon and intialsetup of notificationbuilder@srv_sud

Comment: from where you are calling updatenotification() method ?

Comment: when new song clicked @jk2praj

Comment: have you tried by creating new object of notificationbuilder in updatenofitication() method ?  try changing flag of PendingIntent you are created for setcontentIntent with PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT  or combination of FLAG_ONE_SHOT

Comment: Try update notification when you state change use notificationmanager.notify

Comment: It is very simple. I answered to this here. [Update Notification's action Icon dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59815080/6543967)

Answer (score 2):

To change the icon of action at realtime, you need:

1. Get and replace action.
2. Push new notification.

For example:

```
notificationBuilder.actions[1] = new Notification.Action(R.drawable.pause, "play", pendingIntent);
NotificationManager service = ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE));

service.notify(101, notificationBuilder);
```

or

```
notificationBuilder.actions[1] = new Notification.Action(R.drawable.pause, "play", pendingIntent);
startForeground(101, notificationBuilder);
```

Comment: Luis actions are array of addAction , you can find it mActions[1]