# Update Notification's action Icon dynamically

Tags: android, notifications

I set a notification for a player, I want to update icon after play or pause action from notification.
This is my code for Notification.

```
    private void showNotification(String title, Bitmap bitmap) {

    //region Create Notification
    MediaSessionCompat mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(getApplicationContext(), "session tag");
    MediaSessionCompat.Token token = mediaSession.getSessionToken();
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"PRIMARY_CHANNEL")
             .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_1)
             .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
             .setContentTitle("Simplay")
             .setContentText(title)
             .setOngoing(true)
             .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setContentIntent(notifyPendingIntent)
             .addAction(R.drawable.exo_controls_rewind,"",rewindPendingIntent)
             **.addAction( R.drawable.exo_controls_pause,"",playPendingIntent)**
             .addAction(R.drawable.exo_controls_fastforward,"",forwardPendingIntent)
             .setStyle(new android.support.v4.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
             .setMediaSession(token))
             .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);

    notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = "Notification";
        String description = "";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("PRIMARY_CHANNEL", name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        channel.enableLights(true);
        channel.setShowBadge(false);
        channel.setLockscreenVisibility(123);
        NotificationManager notificationManager1 = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager1.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
    notificationManager.notify(123, mBuilder.build());
    //endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
.addAction(getResources.getDrawable(R.drawable.exo_controls_pause),"",playPendingIntent)
```

Comment: This adds a new action, does not update an old one.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**
To change the icon of action at realtime, you need:

1. Get and replace action.
2. Push new notification.

For example:

```
notificationBuilder.actions[1] = new Notification.Action(R.drawable.pause, "play", pendingIntent);

NotificationManager service = ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE));
service.notify(101, notificationBuilder);
```

or

```
notificationBuilder.actions[1] = new Notification.Action(R.drawable.pause, "play", pendingIntent);
startForeground(101, notificationBuilder);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've found is basically to remove all actions from builder and add them again, then resubmit the notification.

(code in Kotlin)

```
fun startNotification()
{
    _builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
        .setContentText("Title")
        .setContentIntent(_contentIntent)
        .setOngoing(true)

    updateNotification(true) // set initial playing state here
}

fun updateNotification(playing: Boolean)
{
    val playPauseResource = if (playing) R.drawable.pause else R.drawable.play

    _builder
        .clearActions()
        .addAction(R.drawable.prev, "Rewind", _rewindPendingIntent)
        .addAction(playPauseResource, "Play/pause", _playPendingIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.next, "Next", _forwardPendingIntent)

    with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(_context))
    {
        notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, _builder.build())
    }
}
```